# Big Consult Slow When use "ORDER BY"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem when ordering a series of "topics " in a structure of forum, when I do the query generates a list (among millions of records) so fast (0.12 seconds), but when I add the "ORDER BY ordered DESC" the query takes 1 minute.

```
        SELECT 
        forum_topics.id AS id,
        forum_topics.slug AS slug, 
        forum_topics.user_id AS user_id, 
        forum_topics.forum_id AS forum_id, 
        forum_topics.title AS title,
        forum_topics.total_post AS total_post,  
        forum_topics.total_view AS total_view,
        forum_topics.last_post_id AS last_post_id,
        forum_topics.created AS created,
        forum_topics.modified AS modified,
        forum_topics.ordered AS ordered, 
        forum_topics.status_close AS status_close,
        forum_topics.status_view AS status_view, 
        t_users.id AS topic_user_id, 
        t_users.nick AS user_nick, 
        p_users.id AS post_user_id, 
        p_users.nick AS post_user_nick,
        forum_posts.title AS post_title, 
        forum_posts.created AS post_created 
        FROM forum_topics 
        LEFT JOIN forum_posts ON forum_topics.last_post_id = forum_posts.id 
        LEFT JOIN users AS t_users ON forum_topics.user_id = t_users.id 
        LEFT JOIN users AS p_users ON forum_posts.user_id = p_users.id 
        WHERE forum_topics.forum_id = '9' AND forum_topics.status_highlight = '0' 
        LIMIT 0,100
```

Any ideas on how to order this super-table without losing performance?
NOTE: All "id" (PRIMARY) and "*_id" are index, as "ordered" field which is a unix timestamp INT (15)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` allows the sytem to take any 100 records, so it takes the first it finds.

adding the `ORDER BY` says you want some 100 specific records--hence it has to search exactly these records.

how to fix?

try an index on `FORUM_TOPICS (forum_id, status_highlight, ordered)` that index is then already in the order needed by `ORDER BY`--hence, the first (or last) records in the index are the ones you asked for, so the DB can use them straight away.

Comment: I already have all indexed:

PRIMARY BTREE id 8174105 
forum_id BTREE forum_id 7 
user_id BTREE user_id  5
slug BTREE slug 8174105
total_post BTREE total_post 7
ordered BTREE ordered 13
status_view BTREE status_view 2
status_highlight  BTREE status_highlight  2
status_close BTREE status_close 2
created  BTREE created  10713

But the problem persists..

Comment: hi! what I mean, is that you need one singe index that contains those three columns--that is an concatenated index. seems that you are having many individual index. have a look at: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/index-combine-performance

Answer (score 0):

INDEX on ordered field ( timestamp one - you got 3: created, modified, ordered ) and stauts_highlight would not hurt (if it is main where condition)